# will_paginate link to nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the will paginate gem from http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Routes:

```
map.resources :post do |post|
  post.resources :comments
end
```

Post Controller:

```
@post = Post.first
@comments = @post.comments.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
```

My problem lies in the view:

```
<%= will_paginate @comments %>
```

This generates links like /post/1?page=1
What I need is /post/1/comments?page=1

Is there a way to just tell will_paginate what url helper to use? (like `post_comments_path`)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [checking the documentation](http://gitrdoc.com/rdoc/mislav/will_paginate/b3b0f593ea9b1da13a64bc825dfe17b6bbc2828b/classes/WillPaginate/ViewHelpers.html#M000134)? Pass the :param option to `will_paginate` where you can specify things like `:controller` and so on.

Comment: Ok, found my own solution.
I knew about :params option but I was to stuck with named routes that I didn't thought about passing :post_id with the controller and action so that it matches the route again.....

Well, I guess I should never start programming without having coffee first, sry for asking a stupid question.

Comment: Sorry for the rather harsh answer - didn't have my coffee either.

Comment: THe documentation does not mention nested routing